# Computer is OFF, and fans turn on and off twice a day

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, power, fan

We have an OptiPlex 755 desktop acting quite strangely here. It's powered off, not in standby or hibernate, and from time to time it will just start spinning its fans for a few seconds, and then turn off again. (The PSU doesn't have a power switch, so the main board is still getting power.)

My guess is that this is a PSU-issue, since this is also the behavior these computers have when you disconnect/connect the power cable. Yet, when using the computer, there are no noticeable power-interruptions.

Has anyone seen this kind of ghost-computer behavior? Might dust-cleaning the PSU solve it? Or is it more likely to be a component-malfunction?

Comment: I'd buy a new PSU personally, if it's acting like this, I guess it's possible to cause damage to the machine. Or, it's Casper having some fun!!

Comment: While dust-cleaning PSU, clean your motherboard too Also try reinserting bios battery.

Comment: Being soft-off via the "standby" switch is of course **not** being completely powered off.  If your machine **were** in fact completely powered off, with the "on/off" switch on the PSU (or at the mains outlet), there wouldn't be the power to spin the fans at all.

Comment: @JdeBP: True. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

My experience tells me it`s PSU! 97,5% :)

Had this problem several times!
Easiest way to diagnose is to try working/trusted PSU.

I have used non-Optiplex form PSU, but just any with enough power (Watts) and compatible mainboard connector 22/24 pins etc borrowed from my friends/neighbours.

Remember to charge off motherboard with on/off button after removing old PSU to avoid short!

Good luck!